# Why are casts less type-safe than explicit typed variable declarations?

Tags: typescript

I love type safety, which is why I love typescript.

However, I've found situations in which I end up having to explicitly
declare extra variables in order to get the type safety that I need.

**UPDATED EXAMPLE:**

Suppose I want to call ".join" on an array of strings, and I really want to make sure that it's an array of strings (rather than, say, Objects, which would end up getting outputted as `[object Object]`):

If I were to just do this code here, it won't stop me from accidentally passing in an object for `somethingElse`:

If I create an array for the `urlParts` and type it as `string[]`, I can prevent the problem:

```
const baseUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
const somethingElse = { not: "a string" };
const urlParts: string[] = [baseUrl, somethingElse];
window.location.replace(urlParts.join("\n"))
```

However, there doesn't seem to be a way for me to do it without creating a separate `urlParts` variable, which I had been hoping to avoid.  E.g., via one of:

```
window.location.replace(([baseUrl, somethingElse] as string[]).join("\n"))
window.location.replace((<string[]>[baseUrl, somethingElse]).join("\n"))
```

The only way I found to avoid creating a variable is to inline the result as
a self-executing anonymous strongly-typed function -- but that just seems like
a ridiculous workaround:

```
window.location.replace(((): string[] => [baseUrl, somethingElse])().join("\n"))
```

[image: Experimentation in TS Playground]

Is this a TypeScript bug / gap?  Or am I missing something?

I asked a few colleagues to see if they had any ideas,
but we weren't able to figure how to get the stricter types.

Thanks!

Comment: `as number[]` or `<number[]>` doesn't *check* that the array only contains numbers, it *insists to the compiler* that it does. You're bypassing the usual checks. `["hi", 6].forEach(item => item.toExponential(5))` *would* show an error, because the inferred type is `number | string`.

Comment: They're [type assertions](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), not casts.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, you're totally right, in my original example it made no sense that I was casting to `number[]` given that I could have let the compiler just do its work.  See my completely updated example, that draws on a real-world example where I encountered it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) are less safe than [type annotations](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-system.html#basic-annotations) because while both annotations and assertions allow you to *widen* the type of an expression, which is safe for reading, only type assertions allow you to *narrow* the type of an expression, which is unsafe for reading.  The compiler lets you do this because you *assert* that it is true.

As an example... suppose you are given a variable `x` of type `string`.  If you are just reading the value of that variable, it is safe to treat the variable as a wider type like `string | number`.  That's because all values of type `string` are *also* values of type `string | number`.  So both `let y: string | number = x` and `x as string | number` are valid, since the compiler can verify the validity of those expressions.

On the other hand, if you are given a variable `y` of type `string | number`, it is *unsafe* to treat the variable as a *narrower* type like `string`.  That's because there are values of type `string | number` which are *not* values of type `string`.  So `let x: string = y` will give a compiler error; the compiler knows that it is not safe to treat a `string | number` as a `string`.  But `y as string` is allowed, because you are telling the compiler that you know more than it does.  Sometimes the compiler infers a wider type than you can, as in `let y = true ? "a" : 1;`.  "Obviously" `y` will be a `string`, but the compiler does not (as of TS3.3) notice that only the true branch of the ternary operator will be evaluated and so it infers `string | number` for `y`.  So you can assert `y as string` is safe and the compiler will believe you.

Also, as stated in the comments, the term "type assertion" is preferred over "type cast", usually because "type cast" sometimes implies some runtime effect.  TypeScript's type system is completely [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) at runtime, so it's only during design time that the type system does anything.  An assertion is you telling the compiler not to worry if it cannot verify that a particular expression is of a particular type.  If your assertion is correct, then everything is fine.  If your assertion is incorrect, everything *seems* fine at design time, and then you will reap whatever runtime consequences befall you.

Type assertions aren't *completely* unsafe; it is still possible for the compiler to balk at asserting `x as T` if the type inferred for `x` is neither narrower nor wider than the type `T`.  For example, if you have a variable `z` of type `string` and you write `z as number` the compiler will still warn you.  In such cases you can still force the compiler into submission by noting that you can always first widen to a common supertype or narrow to a common subtype before continuing on.  The type [`unknown`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#new-unknown-top-type) is a commmon supertype of all types, so you can always write `z as unknown as number` and silence any possible objection from the compiler.

Also note that the `x as T` syntax for type assertions does exactly the same thing as the `<T> x` syntax.  The only reason there are two ways to write that is because [angle brackets don't play nicely with JSX](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#the-as-operator).

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

---

UPDATE: the least tedious way I can think to gain the safety of type annotations in an inline manner is to use a helper function.  This isn't quite as crazy as the IIFE you're using, but it's similar.  Here's how I'd do it:

```
const ann = <T>(x: T) => x;
```

The function `ann` (short for "annotate") allows you to explicitly annotate the type of the passed-in argument.  Let's see:

```
window.location.replace(ann<string[]>([baseUrl, somethingElse]).join("\n"))
// error on somethingElse, as expected
```

Does that work well enough for you?

Comment: thanks for your reply.  I have updated my question with a better example of where the lack of type safety bit me today.  I guess my question remains: is there any way to make an "inlined" type assertion, without declaring a whole new variable?

Comment: I love the workaround, that makes it much more reasonable.  I'll start using that.  Do you think it's worth suggesting such use-case to TypeScript though, to make this be a more "proper" feature?  Ideally this feels like something that would be built into the language, not something that requires writing a utility for (nor that has runtime impact, however small)...

Comment: In any case, though, thanks for your help!  Marked your answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: For anyone reading this:  sounds like this same request/need is being tracked by https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481